# For what values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the derivative of the function is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

For what values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the derivative of the function is bounded?

Let $f_{\alpha,\beta}(t)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
    t^\alpha \sin(t^\beta) &   si  &  0 < t \leq 1 \\
    \\ 0 &  si & t = 0 
   \end{array}
   \right.$

Then $$|f'_{\alpha,\beta}(t)|=|\alpha t^{\alpha-1}\sin(t^\beta)+\beta t^{\alpha + \beta-1 }\cos(t^\beta)|\leq|\alpha t^{\alpha-1}\sin(t^\beta)| +|\beta t^{\alpha + \beta-1 }\cos(t^\beta)| $$

I know that $|\sin(t^\beta)| \leq 1 $ and $|\cos(t^\beta)| \leq 1$ but here i'm stuck. can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start you off: if $\alpha > 1$ and $\beta\ge 0$, both terms in $f'_{\alpha,\beta}(t)$ go to $0$ as $t \to 0$.  Now consider the other cases...